# New weapon (cat o'nine flails) stats balanced?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, weapons, balance, homebrew-review

A cat o'nine **fl**ails, a new weapon of my devising, is a 9 headed flail similar to an Ochsenherde. Note that this is not to be confused with a cat o'nine **t**ails.

[image: Picture of a weapon with nine spiked heads on separate chains attached to the same handle]

*Artist's impression* - [Original image source](http://www.melbar.eu/Mittelalter-Shop/Blankwaffen/Stangenwaffen-Shop/Ochsenherde--Morgenstern-3-Kugeln_M2S5528.html)

What is the best way to stat a weapon such as this in D&D 3.5e? My initial suggestions is as a two-handed Exotic Weapon with 1d12 damage and a 20×2 critical.

Are these stats viable/reasonable when compared with other weapons in D&D 3.5?  If not, how do I make this weapon viable/reasonable?

If no other opinion then how would you make it balanced?

Comment: Is this weapon wielded with one hand or with two? Why has it a damage roll similar to two-handed weapons? A nine-tailed flail istn't really a good weapon anyway, difficult to wield... Can you explain why you haven't chosen stats similar to other weapons in the category? Also, I'm not sure if this question isn't too opinion-based.

Comment: @DoomedMind Asking for a balance estimate is *an* opinion, but it can be an informed, expert opinion that's based on game texts and experience. That moves the question from *What do you think of this?* to *Is this appropriate based on existing material?* The site looks askance the former but can handle the latter.

Comment: Have you compared this to other weapons in D&D 3.5 yourself?  How do you find that it stacks up to other exotic weapons?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The stats you have suggested seem a bit too weak, if anything. As written there's no reason to take it over a Greatsword! I think there are a couple of ways to go about this unusual piece of equipment.

**1. Use stats for an existing weapon.**
The simple thing to do would be to just use it as a 'Heavy Flail' by another name.

This would make it a two-handed Martial weapon with 1d10 damage, 19-20x2 critical and Bludgeoning damage. It would also give bonuses to Disarm rolls and allow the user to make Trip attacks. This last point seems a common property among flails in D&D 3.5

**2. Design a new profile**
If you go down this route then it would certainly count as an Exotic weapon and is very likely to be wielded two-handed. It should also be a straight upgrade over the Heavy Flail to justify needing a feat to wield it.

Here you could just increase the damage by one step up to a D12 and call it a day. If you really wanted to push the boat out, then upping the damage further still to 2D6 would effectively make it a Greatsword with some fancy properties - which seems reasonable for an Exotic weapon.

If going down this route, don't forget to keep the Disarm/Trip traits which seem inherent to all flail weapons.